# QGIS Sort a field with delimiter into a list

Tags: qgis-3

I'm trying to get a delimited string in a single field into a list breaking to a new line at the delimeter. I've played around with the array functions to turn the list into an array based on the delimiter but can't make it into a list within the multiline Text Edit box in a dialog.
String is like this:
X000053437,2014-07-23,0359171,AA;X000086283,,0392438,BB;X000110251,,APB90P50UU,CC;X000126723,,03094,DD
but I want it to appear like this:

X000053437,2014-07-23,0359171,AA;

X000086283,,0392438,BB;

X000110251,,APB90P50UU,CC;

X000126723,,03094,DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Field Calculator, you can replace the delimiter with the new line special character `\n`:

```sql
replace("list_field", ';', '\n')
```

[image]

If you want to keep the semicolon, replace with `;\n`

Comment: Thank you Matt - trying to be too clever and forgot to keep it simple!

Comment: I am familiar with this struggle. Things are often far simpler than we initially think.